# How to insert a dot in a cell in a longtable

Tags: longtable, bullets

I am trying to insert a `\cdot` into a cell in a `longtable`. Doing so results in an error though.

This works:

```
\begin{longtable}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{8cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{8cm}|}
    ...
    one & two\\
    three & four\\
\end{longtable}
```

This does not work:

```
\begin{longtable}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{8cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{8cm}|}
    ...
    one & two\\
    \cdot three & four\\
\end{longtable}
```

What must I do to print a `\cdot`?

Comment: Math mpde: `$\cdot$`

Comment: Thanks  @Bernard ! Solved the problem! Why do I need that? Is that called an escape syntax?

Comment: I's just that `\cdot` is defined as a  math binary symbol. If you have a direct access from your keyboard to the centred dot `·` (Unicode 00B7) and use the `utf8` input encoding, you may try it.